# How to change username and password on IIS sites

Tags: c#, .net, iis, credentials

I've been triying to change credentials of IIS sites on ServerManager.sites like;

```
  ServerManager server = new ServerManager();
            SiteCollection sites = server.Sites;

            foreach (Site site in sites)
            {

            }
```

But there is no attribute to change credentials attributes such as Username/Password.
How to access these attributes to set Username/Password on c# ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qw2vZ.png)

Comment: Must be a real user in the server where iis is deployed, you can't change it there, need something that manages ActiveDirectory

Comment: 1) Learn what are sites/applications/virtual directories, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis 2) Credentials can only be configured at virtual directory level, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.administration.virtualdirectory.password?view=iis-dotnet

Answer (score 0):

I've wrote the to code change IIS Sıtes Instance Settings && Application Pools on IIS settings.

```
    private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string errorMessage = "";

            if (CheckUserNameOrPasswordIsNotEmptyAndEqual() && CheckCredentials(out errorMessage))
            {
                ReadIISSitesByCommand();
                FindApplicationPoolsonIIS();
            }
        }
        private bool CheckUserNameOrPasswordIsNotEmptyAndEqual()
        {
            return ((textUserName.Text.Assigned() && textPassword.Text.Assigned() && txtPasswordConfirm.Text.Assigned()) &&  (textPassword.Text == txtPasswordConfirm.Text));
        }
        private void ChangeUsernameAndPasswordOfApplication(ServerManager serverManager, ApplicationPool pool)
        {
            try
            {
                pool.ProcessModel.IdentityType = ProcessModelIdentityType.SpecificUser;
                pool.ProcessModel.UserName = textUserName.Text;
                pool.ProcessModel.Password = textPassword.Text;

                serverManager.CommitChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                NLogger.Instance().Error("ChangeUsernameAndPasswordOfApplication", ex);
            }
        }

        private void ChangeSitesOnIIS(string path)
        {
            try
            {
                if (path.Assigned())
                {
                    string commandString = "%systemroot%\\system32\\inetsrv\\APPCMD.exe set vdir /vdir.name:\"" + path + "\" /userName:\"" + textUserName.Text + "\" /password:\"" + textPassword.Text + "\"";
                    ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + commandString);

                    processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                    processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                    processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

                    Process process = Process.Start(processInfo);
                    process.WaitForExit();
                    process.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                NLogger.Instance().Error("ChangeSitesOnIIS", ex);
            }
        
        }

        private void ReadIISSitesByCommand()
        {
            ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + @"C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe LIST VDIRS");
            processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

            processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

            Process process = Process.Start(processInfo);
            process.WaitForExit();

            string standardOutput;
            while ((standardOutput = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (standardOutput.ToLower().Contains("domainname"))
                {
                    standardOutput = standardOutput.Split(new string[] { "\"" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
                    standardOutput = standardOutput.Split(new string[] { "\"" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];
                    ChangeSitesOnIIS(standardOutput);
                }
            }
            process.Close();
            layout_IISSuccess.Text = " IIS site settings saved. \n ";
        }

        private void FindApplicationPoolsonIIS()
        {
            try
            {
                using (ServerManager server = new ServerManager())
                {
                    ApplicationPoolCollection applicationPools = server.ApplicationPools;
                    foreach (ApplicationPool pool in applicationPools)
                    {
                        if (pool.Name.ToLower().Contains("pooname"))
                            ChangeUsernameAndPasswordOfApplication(server, server.ApplicationPools[pool.Name]);
                    }

                    layout_IISSuccess.Text += "IIS pool settings saved.";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                NLogger.Instance().Error("FindApplicationPoolsonIIS", ex);
            }
        }

        private bool IsValidDomainUser(string userName, string password)
        {
            string domain = System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName;
            userName = userName.Split(new[] { "\\" }, StringSplitOptions.None).Last();

            using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain))
                    return pc.ValidateCredentials(userName, password);
        }
        private bool IsValidWindowsUser(string userName, string password)
        {
            using (PrincipalContext p = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine))
                return p.ValidateCredentials(userName, password);
        }

        private bool CheckCredentials(out string Error)
        {
            bool isValid = false;
            try
            {
                if(IsValidDomainUser(textUserName.Text, textPassword.Text))
                {
                    isValid = true;
                    Error = "";
                }
                else if (IsValidWindowsUser(textUserName.Text, textPassword.Text))
                {
                    isValid = true;
                    Error = "";
                }
                else
                { 
                    Error = "Username/Password Error";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                NLogger.Instance().Error("CheckCredentials", ex);
                Error = "Username/Password Error";
            }
            return isValid;
        }
```